# How is a Directed Acyclic Graph implemented in Hadoop or Spark?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop2, directed-acyclic-graphs

I keep on getting the term DAG in different contexts in Hadoop ecosystem like

> when any action is called on the RDD, Spark creates the DAG and submits it to the DAG scheduler

or

> DAG model is a strict generalization of MapReduce model

How it is implemented in Hadoop or Spark ?

Comment: Go through [this link](http://data-flair.training/blogs/directed-acyclic-graph-dag-in-apache-spark/) and [this link](https://www.sigmoid.com/apache-spark-internals/). This should answer most of your questions. Also, DAG is a Spark related thing. DAG execution is different from MapReduce.

Answer (score 1):

The very first DAG you (as a Spark developer) will "run into" is when you apply transformations to your dataset as a RDD.

After you create a RDD (by loading dataset from an external storage or creating one from a local collection) you start with a single-node **RDD lineage**.

```
val nums = sc.parallelize(0 to 9)
scala> nums.toDebugString
res0: String = (8) ParallelCollectionRDD[1] at parallelize at <console>:24 []
```

Right after a transformation, like `map`, you create another RDD with the initial one being its parent.

```
val even = nums.map(_ * 2)
scala> even.toDebugString
res1: String =
(8) MapPartitionsRDD[2] at map at <console>:26 []
 |  ParallelCollectionRDD[1] at parallelize at <console>:24 []
```

And so on. By transforming an RDD using transformation operators you build a graph of transformations that is a RDD lineage that is simply a **directed acyclic graph of RDD dependencies**.

The other DAG you may be told about is when you execute an action on a RDD that will lead to a Spark job. That Spark job on the RDD will get eventually mapped to a set of stages (by `DAGScheduler`) that again create a graph of stages that is a **directed acyclic graph of stages**.

There are no other DAGs in Spark.

I can't comment on Hadoop.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Spark

`lines = spark.textfile("hdfs://<file_path>",2)`.

Here lines rdd have 2 partitions.
In above diagram say A ,B,C and D are such rdds have 2 partitions each (red boxes).
As in diagram each rdd is result of transformation.
Basically dependencies between rdds is classified in narrow and wide dependencies.
Narrow dependencies are formed where each partition of parent rdd is used by only one partition of child rdd, while shuffling of data results in to wide dependencies.

All the narrow dependencies form stage 1 and wide dependency form stage 2.

**Such stages form directed acyclic graph**

And these stages are then submitted to task scheduler.

Hope this helps.